# gnuplot: Points overlap in pm3d with a wide xrange

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to plot three dimentions of data using pm3d. I'm trying to plot the number of times an event occurs (z value) with respect to the day of the year (x value) and hour of the day (y value).

Using pm3d works great for up to a range of 600 (rought 2 years of data). However, the points begin to overlap each other when a wider range is required.

I believe this is related to the fact that gnuplot isn't stretching the plot to the full size specified in set terminal. I haven't however been able to find a setting that controls this directly.

the script I'm using:

```
set terminal png size 10000, 1000
set output "%s_plot.png"
set title "%s's"
set ytics 1,1
set xtics 1
set xrange[0:%s]
set yrange[0:23]
set cbrange[0:%s]
set pm3d map 
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "blue", 31 "red")
splot '%s.data'
```

aspect of the plot for a range of [0:1000] in x:

[image]

aspect of the plot for a range of [0,100] in x:

[image]

(the images above are just snippets of the whole thing)

What can I do to remedy this? Perhaps the solution is manually setting the points (squares) to have a fixed width.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the kind of plot that you want, I would replace your last line with:

```
plot '%s.data' matrix with image
```

Comment: I replaced the line with plot '%s.data' with image, because my data file is not in matrix format. it worked, thanks!

Comment: by the way, a related question. I wish to use the "set rectangle" command to create background sections to differentiate portions of the graph I'm sketching (weekends to be precise). I'm following the guide at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rectangle.html (last example). However, using "plot with image" hides the rectangles completely, because there is no transparency in the image. --http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/233/pohpinaplot.png). I wish to make the grey color transparent, but I don't think that's possible, am I right?

Comment: ok, nevermind. I managed to do it with plot with rgbalpha instead of plot with image :D